# PHPUNIT Test - Expected Status 200 But Received 500

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I keep getting status 500 when 200 is expected. These are the files:

**ExampleTest.php**

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**This is the result returned**

```
PHPUnit 7.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.F                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 1.86 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:133
/var/www/html/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

**This is the Laravel log file**

```
[2018-10-15 20:56:09] testing.ERROR: Call to a member function load() on null (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/app.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Call to a member function load() on null (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/app.blade.php) at /var/www/html/app/Ezybyz/Configuration/ProvidesScriptVariables.php:46, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function load() on null at /var/www/html/app/Ezybyz/Configuration/ProvidesScriptVariables.php:46)
```

**app.blade.php**

```
@php
$config = array_merge(
    Ezybyz::scriptVariables(), [
        // Add key and value here if you want to added to initial state
    ]
)
@endphp

@extends('layouts.main')

@push('meta')
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
{{-- Fix for chunk error in Webpack and Vue-Router --}}
<base href="/" />
@endpush

@push('favicon')
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico?v=2') }}" type="image/x-icon" />
@endpush

@push('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
@endpush

@push('header_js')
{{--  EzyByz initial state provider --}}
<script>
  window.App = @json($config)
</script>
{{-- Add whitelisted routes for making API calls --}}
@routes
@endpush

@push('title')
<title>{{ config('app.name') }} </title>
@endpush

@section('content')
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <app />
</div>
@endsection

@push('footer_js')
@if(config('echo.realtime'))
{{-- Load socket.io --}}
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
@endif

<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@endpush
```

**ProvidesScriptVariables.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Ezybyz\Configuration;

use App\Ezybyz\Ezybyz;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Ezybyz\Contracts\InitialFrontendState;

trait ProvidesScriptVariables
{
    /**
     * Get the default JavaScript variables for Spark.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function scriptVariables()
    {
        return [
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            'env' => config('app.env'),
            'api_endpoint' => config('ezybyz.app.api'),
            'sponsor' => self::getSponsor(),
        ];
    }

    protected static function getState()
    {
        return Ezybyz::call(InitialFrontendState::class . '@forUser', [Auth::user()]);
    }

    protected static function getSponsor()
    {
        if ($link = request()->referrallink) {
            $user = Ezybyz::user()->find($link->user_id);

            return [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'profile' => $user->profile,
            ];
        }
        // We Will Return a Default Sponsor
        else {
            $user = Ezybyz::user()->first()->load('profile');

            return [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'profile' => $user->profile,
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the error message says that the error happens in app.blade.php please share this file with us.

Comment: @TimSch: Added contents of app.blade.php. Thanks

Comment: ok your error message says that you're calling load() on null. I can't see any load call. So I would dig a bit deeper. Is this Ezbyz class made by yourself? I would Expect that we will find the scriptVariables() at line 46 of the ProvidesScriptVariables.php file. Please post this too.

Comment: @TimSch: Added contents of ProvidesScriptVariables.php

Comment: Somehow, after I delete and rebuild the docker volumes and images, the test passed without issue now. However, when I push to Gitlab and it perform the test again, it failed with the same error, ie. Expect 200 but received 500

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `RefreshDatabase` trait in the test class:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` before `$response = $this->get('/');` to get more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this error message is, you don't have the openssl
 php
 extension enabled.

Answer (score 0):

just edit your class to return true

```
namespace Tests\Feature;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
    
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

then run test in your command

`vendor/bin/phpunit`

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late but may help new comers.

**Is your XAMPP/WAMP server running check and make sure it is running.**

because 500 is an internal serve error and it mainly occurs when your server is not responding or not running properly.

hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

Do check with your routes. Check if you have provided 'name' to your base route.

eg:
In routes/web.php, Do the following:

```
Route::get('home','BlogController@home')->name('home');
```

Now go to the test case and do replace the following code:

```
$response = $this->get('home');
```

Let me know if it works for you.